# Uploading assignment answers - for prospective employers?

Tags: application, homework

This question is similar to: ['Sharing assignments with a potential employer'](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/66566/75368)

However, it is not quite the same, and does not answer my query fully.

My question is: I have been thinking about ways of sharing my course assignment work with prospective employers. The rationale is that, if I just write 'statistics 70%' on my resume, it is difficult for the employer to know what that means, in high resolution. The employer really doesn't know the level of questions asked, how lenient the marking was, which bits I got wrong, and how that affects my suitability for the job. If I could signpost my interviewer to a collection of work I have produced, they can look in detail at what I understand and don't understand.

However, this has implications for my university, in that (depending upon how I upload the assignments) they might be easier for future students to access and therefore make plagriarism easier.

Could I upload the files to the cloud with password protection and offer to provide the password at the request of the interviewer?

I know this system still isn't perfect, since once the prospective employer has access to the files, there is no way of knowing if they will reproduce them elsewhere on the web or what they will do with them.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66566/sharing-assignments-with-a-potential-employer

Answer (score 3):

Most employers do not want to see your work.  They want to see grades/marks because it is easy for them.  Only bother if an employer asks for it or you work in a field where a "portfolio" is common.

Post only your own work, not the materials provided by faculty.  This eliminates all concerns about plagiarism.  We do not know your university's intellectual property policy.

> might be easier for future students to access and therefore make plagiarism easier.

Post the materials after the course is over.  If the faculty decide to give the same assignment again in the future, that's the faculty's problem, not yours.

The purpose of education is to make learning easier, not to make cheating harder.

Comment: Some honor codes might make posting a violation. In some situations the assignments are the most valuable part of the course design.

Comment: @Buffy posting what exactly might be a violation?

Comment: Posting any information about assignments - especially solutions.

Comment: @Buffy Can you give an example of a university that forbids posting solutions to an assignment on the internet after a course is complete?  And is this an academic integrity violation?

Comment: The Dartmouth honor code states that a student should not give or receive prohibited aid in tests or assignments. This is interpreted pretty broadly, across years.

Comment: I'll note that, in CS at least, some programming assignments are carefully crafted within a minimal environment to help the students gain insight. They are difficult to create and even harder to modify for future use. They aren't just pro forma practice. But things like recursion are difficult and subtle for many students.

Comment: @Buffy Are you sure about Dartmouth?  I cannot find anything relevant to my answer at this link. https://student-affairs.dartmouth.edu/policy/academic-honor-principle

Comment: Different parts of the Dartmouth ecosystem state their own principles. I copied from the medical school which references the general code. The Dartmouth honor code is very old and is carefully maintained and enforced. It requires reporting by students of violations they notice. Some violations make the news, actually.

Comment: And suppose a professor just asks students not to post solutions to assignments, now or in the future. Would you honor that? Suppose they explain why?

Comment: Well, @Buffy, it says "Give or receive prohibited aid in tests or assignments."  I advised the asker to only post materials after the course is over.  That is clearly not "in" a test or assignment, it is "out."  I didn't read the whole thing.  https://geiselmed.dartmouth.edu/students/document/student-policy-handbook/student-conduct-and-responsibilities/the-student-honor-code/

Comment: @Buffy If I were a student at Dartmouth Medical School, I would point out that the honor code says we should encourage a "collaborative environment" and that means posting information on the internet after a course is over is a good thing to do.  It's absurd to suggest students cannot use what they learn in a course.  The whole point of the course was to enable students to reuse what they learned, including answers to assignments.

Comment: "Using what they learned" and posting answers is hardly the same thing. Yes, Dartmouth permits collaboration, but only when the professor in the course explicitly enables it. Otherwise it strictly forbids it. The link you posted clearly says that.

Comment: Well, I strongly disagree.  Post your own answer if you want.